# Find the original price of a bag of fruits?

Tags: word-problem

One week Jordan bought a bag of fruits at the local market.The next week he saw the bag was on sale for 20℅ off the previously marked price.Jordan bought two more bags at the reduced price and spent $20.54 in total for the three bags

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. What have you tried?

Comment: 20 percent off means 80 of orginal price equals .8 times original price.  If $p$ is original price, Jordan spent $p + .8p + .8p$ and that is $\$20.54$.  So what is $p$?

Answer (score 0):

Take $x$ to be the original price. Jordan buys one bag at this price.  The next week he buys 2 bags for $0.8x$ each after allowing 20% off.
The total amount paid by him for the 3 bags is $x+0.8x\times 2$=$2.6x$=20.54 (given).
Thus $x=7.9$.